# iPhone Plist to NSDictionary shows a black screen

Tags: iphone, xml, serialization, plist

I am developing an iphone application, my intent is to retrieve a plist from a web server and show the results in an tableview.

I am having an issue when trying to deserialize the plist. The following code compiles but at run time the iphone simulator screen stays black, it seems to me that the view never gets loaded and the NSLog messages don´t show up in the console. On the other hand if I debug the messages do get printed in the console but the view doesn´t come up the screen stays black:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {


NSData *data = [@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?> <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC \"-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN\" \"http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd\"><plist version=\"1.0\"><dict><key>count</key><array><integer>5</integer></array><key>username</key><array><string>johnsmith</string></array></dict></plist>" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


NSString *error = nil;

NSPropertyListFormat *format;

NSMutableDictionary *plist = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:data 
                                 mutabilityOption:0 
                                        format: format
                                 errorDescription:&error];



if (!plist) {  
    NSLog(@"Error reading plist from file, error = '%s'", [error UTF8String]);  
    [error release];  
}  else {

    NSLog(@"Groovy");
    NSLog(@"Count: %d",[plist count]);
    NSLog(@"Username %@", [plist objectForKey:@"username"]);
    NSLog(@"Count %@", [plist objectForKey:@"count"]);
    //[plist retain];

}


//[plist dealloc];


[super viewDidLoad];
}
```

I´ve been researching and they say that the NSPropertyListSerialization leaks memory, I am not sure if that´s my case. In case you want to try out this code I just created an iphone view based application and pasted the code into the (void)viewDidLoad  method.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but you're not doing anything with the deserialized PLIST. Also, is the code part of an `UIView` ? If so, have you implemented the `drawRect:` method or added subviews ?

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like this:

```
NSPropertyListFormat format;

NSMutableDictionary *plist = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:data 
                                                              mutabilityOption:0 
                                                                        format:&format
                                                              errorDescription:&error];
```

I.e. remove the `*` in front of the first `format` and add a `&` to the second one

`NSPropertyListFormat` is not an object, it is an enum, and `propertyListFromData:                                                        mutabilityOption:format:errorDescription:` wants a pointer to an instance of `NSPropertyListFormat`.

You were passing a not initialized pointer, and the method tried to write to this "random" address. Which lead to a crash.